# Name of this northern pine fishing lure?

Tags: water, fishing-tackle, gear-identification

Can any tell me the name of this fishing lure or where I might find a distributor?

[image]

Comment: How do you know the lure is made from Pine? It could be plastic.  Or is Northern Pine the brand name of the lure?  Or are you referring to the fish (i.e. Walleyed Pike or Walleye) that it's attached to?  Can you edit your question to add more clarity?

Comment: Getting the exact brand and make will be difficult, that type is often referred to as a jointed lure and Rapala makes a similar one under the name Rapala Jointed, the color is not one they currently make but is similar. https://www.rapala.com/rapala/lures/all-other-lures/jointed/Jointed.html Although that particular one looks to be an older style based on the hardware

Comment: "Northern Pike" maybe?